# Will giving 9/12v to a quolcomm quickcharge device kill it?

Tags: power, battery-charging, cellphone

## Background

I recently broke my phone's USB port (damn!), so as a stopgap measure before I can be bothered to buy and fit a replacement, I've soldered two wires to the +ve and -ve wires of where the port used to be  and I've fitted a barrel jack on the outside to act as a makeshift charging port. I've got a problem, however, that it only draws ~500mA. This is very slow for charging. I believe that this is due to it trying to conform with the USB 2.0 standerd (i.e. no more than 500mA).

## Actual question

My phone has Qualcomm quickcharge. Can I feed 9 or 12 volts directly to the USB power pins, or is it neccessary to perform some kind of handshake first? (i.e. do I have to take it all apart again and solder on USB data wires?) Or, is there any other way I can increase the charging speed?

Thanls in advance.

Comment: A lot of phones look for arrangements of resistors on the D+ and D- lines to determine the charger capability.  If they see none, they limit to 500mA, but the charger itself will flag it to draw the rated current.  Google that or measure your charger data lines' resistance to +5 and GND, and replicate that.

Comment: The standard voltage on USB is 5.0 vdc. I believe you will destroy the device if you apply much more than 5.5 vdc. You need a "regulator" to reduce the voltage to 5 vdc. But note well that 5 vdc USB power supplies are quite low cost and plentifully available.

Comment: @xstack yes, I have been using 5v but since quickcharge actually sends up to 12v through the USB power lines, I was wondering if I could just stick 12v on them and cause the phone to draw more power.

Comment: My phone uses 9V  12V would probably damage it.